# Springsource Tool Suite and creating an Application from scratch

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have looked around for a beginners tutorial to start creating a Spring app using the STS IDE.  There seems to be nothing around, its either hand build it or the tutorial doesn't work and is many versions off the current IDE.  I am very new to Spring and need to get going on this. Any links you can throw my way I would appreciate it.

Comment: I am like you and still looking for a good tutorial. I have 15 years of experience in programming, mostly visual studio C++ and C# .NET. I have also worked several months with java with netbeans jsp and tomcat. I have not worked with eclipse before beyond the helloworld stage. I "inherited" a springsource sts (with maven) big project and have spent days trying to find a good tutorial to this dev environment in vain. The spring source site is very self glorifying and offers tutorials to people that struggled for years with Java IDEs like eclipse and other build tools - not for beginners.

Comment: Thanks for the kick in the pants, I will try and get my tutorial done as it might help others who are coming into it like I did.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the green beans series from springsource is a good start: http://blog.springsource.com/2010/11/09/green-beans-putting-the-spring-in-your-step-and-application/

Integrated in the IDE is also a task focused tutorial to learn basic steps inside the ide ( help->task focused tutorials...

Comment: I am completely new to Spring and its IDE.  WHat I find lacking is the step by step instructions for newbies.  Seems everyone assumes you know how to deploy to the embedded tc Server or even just start a webapp from scratch.  Thanks for the help I will look into the link.

Comment: Sorry this is not it. This article is the same as the other tutorials on the springsource site, it starts with the usual "we are the de facto standard..." and then starts immediately talking about advanced building topics that are comprehensible to senior eclipse developers with years of experience with java IDEs.

Answer (score 7):

STS provides Template Projects. Open **File -> New -> Spring Template Project**.
Now you can choose the type of application you want to create. If you want to create a web application choose **Spring MVC Project**. This will create a complete project with a controller, a view, maven integration and everything else you need. You can immediately run this application in tc Server.

Comment: Be careful though, as the latest sprint template as of today is bugged (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927379/unable-to-run-spring-template-project-on-sts/).

Comment: You're right. Quick workaround: Add @RequestMapping("/") Annotation to controller class. See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/IDE-1224

Comment: Fwiw, I too was struggling with finding relevant tutorials for STS until I saw this comment. So I did as Florian suggested and went straight in with a template project, it did indeed run first time on the integrated tc Server. I then exported the project (WAR file), uploaded to a live instance of Tomcat I've got running (just to see what would happen) and again, it worked straight off the bat. Impressive. Although tc Server is Tomcat underneath so no reason wy it shouldn't work I guess. Florian's comment should be step 1 on the [Tutorials page][1] ;-) [1]: http://www.springsource.org/tutorials

Answer (score 3):

I may be late, but I think this tutorial might be helpful (for those who are looking for sts tutorial like me):
http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=2373

UPD:
and this one is good:
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-spring-3-mvc-introduction-spring-mvc-framework/

Comment: Great blob and better late than never!